# IE Border radius display error

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a weird issue with border radius and IE 9+.

The browsers are displaying the rounded corners in the left side like in the images attached.
If you encountered such problems let me know your solution.

I am also attaching an example of CSS I am using for success message:

```
width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #beff97;
color: #68bd45;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

EDIT: I have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1">`

here is the fiddle for what i am doing there:
http://jsfiddle.net/afXWu/

[image: Print screen of IE9].

Comment: You mean you encounter this problem while styling inputs, right ? Inputs being partly native always have been hard to completely style.

Comment: yes, that's right. But the message is just a simple div.

Comment: could you show us working example? like in http://jsfiddle.net/ or somewhere...

Comment: Could you try adding `border-corner-shape: round` ?

Comment: @Davor I updated my question, dystroy I am trying it now, 1 second

Comment: Your vendor-prefixed properties should go BEFORE the standards version. Also you should remove any `X-UA-Compatible` meta or set it to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` if you absolutely must have it.

Comment: I've just tested your jsfiddle demo with my IE9+ and had no issues whatsoever related to the incorrect display of border-radius property. There must be something wrong with your HTML.

Comment: You aren't closing your `meta` tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1"/> <- that last slash should be present. Or you can try this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your jsfiddle demo with my IE9+ and had no issues whatsoever related to the incorrect display of border-radius property.

IE9 (emulation)

[image]

IE11

[image]

**EDIT**

You aren't closing your `meta` tag

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1"/>` <- that last slash should be present.

Or you can try this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`.

Comment: May I add that you're emulating IE9 using IE11, which is an inaccurate way of seeing how IE9 would actually render it. For the most accurate results, actually use IE9 or run it on a VM.

Comment: @Daniel Johnson, I agree, but at this moment I don't have the actual IE9, so have to use an emulation.
I've tested it in IE11 as well and all is good. I'll add another screenshot with IE11.

Comment: @user3529729 somehow that slash at the end of meta tag partially solved the problem. Now it's shows randomly the error So I will check your answer as valid. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the outline property:

```
outline:none;
```