# IE (11) unable to render perfect circles?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I want to render simple CSS circles like this:

```css
.button {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Nothing special. The result should be like this:

[image: good circle]

http://jsfiddle.net/8qvp3oL5/

However, Internet Explorer renders it like this:

[image: bad circle]

It kind of looks like IE cuts the element off by half a pixel on the right and bottom side.

I have already played around with the width, height and border-radius variables, but there is never an improvement. For instance the size does not matter at all, this effect can be seen in any case. IE always cuts off half a pixel on the right and bottom side.

Curiously the same happens with a simple SVG image, that is just a white circle like that.

Is Internet Explorer (11) really unable to render any kind of perfect circle?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that this only happens when the element is positioned on subpixels - e.g. when the element is centered within the viewport etc.

I noticed this while trying to test the same thing in a pure HTML + CSS file rather than via jsfiddle. I couldn't reproduce it there initially, until I figured out that it happens when the element is positioned relatively. e.g. when you center the element or position it relative values like 46.5% etc.

The effect can be seen on jsfiddle, because the container of the iframe isn't positioned in absolute pixel values.

So the question is: is there a way to somehow make an element be positioned on discrete pixel values? At least on screens with a dppx of 1.

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius: 50%;`? And there is never *perfect circle* in computers world

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. I have also tried with `border-radius:30px` or something even higher or `100%` (all browsers automatically cut that down to the half width/height of the element), but it does not change anything. Also I disagree, there is a clearly defined way of rasterizing anti aliased circles in "the computer world" ;).

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220551/ie-border-radius-display-error

Comment: @Rob not really, this is about something else.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done without JavaScript. CSS cannot round. So use a little JS to round the size of the container to an even number of pixels; then you can center.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so. Though I'll probably not do that anyway. No point in doing _that_ much effort just to get rid of a fairly minor visual problem in an old web rendering engine :)

Comment: @fritzmg Well, at work I've got a comptuer with Windows 8.1, that won't run Edge. So IE11 is the most recent Microsoft browser that can run on it. Not that I use IE much, but I'm just saying.

Comment: Sure, but it's not like this is a usability breaking visual bug. Also doing what you proposed with JavaScript wouldn't be simple at, since it also depends on any vertical pixel sizes and how exactly the rendered element is positioned within any parent.